# Receive an event on direct page visit from address bar, Angular JS - ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

guys I am working on an angular js app which uses `ui-router` for deep linking and routing. I want to set up a variable on the `$rootScope` every time a state is visited/changed. I am able to accomplish that on subsequent state transitions via listening to `$stateChangeSuccess` but since the app is deep linked, I want to set the same variable when a state is directly hit from the address bar.

When I hit a specific URL from address bar e.g. Home/Summary/Change, `$stateChangeSuccess` doesn't fire hence I am not able to set the value.

Any suggestions on how I can listen to EACH state visit on my `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this. I was not able to get `$stateChangeSuccess` on the first visit to a page so on initialization i called the function explicitly.

example code

```
var handle = function(){
//do something ...
}

$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', handle); // call handle on each state change
handle(); // will only be called on initialization
```

might not be the cleanest way but it works

Answer (score 1):

You may use combination of `$locationChangeStart` and `$route.current`:

```js
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
  if(!$route.current) {
    $rootScope.myVar = ...
  }
});
```

Comment: still not able to receive $locationChangeStart event when i access #/Home/Summary/Change directly

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime they have implemented a `$urlRouterProvider` where you can add a when:

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // when there is an empty route, redirect to /index   
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/index');

    // You can also use regex for the match parameter
    $urlRouterProvider.when(/aspx/i, '/index');
})
```

So if you like to have Home/Summary/Change matching a state, you would write something like `$urlRouterProvider.when('Home/Summary/Change','myhomestate')` then the $stateChangeSuccess should fire correct.
For more details about that provider look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider